# Filtering SonataMediaBundle media on CKEditor browser depending on model?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, ckeditor, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

My requirement is rather simple: I need a rich text editor with the ability to upload images in a Symfony 2 based system. I installed SonataMediaBundle and CoopTilleulsCKEditorSonataMediaBundle.

However, there's a twist. Images have to be linked to a department, which makes me think there has to be a `OneToMany` relationship from `Department` to `Media`. I can understand that, but that isn't enough as only the images that belong to a `Department` should be able to be picked from the file browser.

Sadly there isn't a lot of documentation around to know how to let CKEditor know which entities must be filtered, or where I am supposed to do this without building a completely custom browser from scratch. Moreover, the browser should not be able to display images from other `Department`s.

What am I missing here? Is there something I should be understanding that I am not?

Comment: I used FMElfinderBundle before, it integrates nicely into CKEditor and has plenty of documentation and extension points. https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle

Comment: Well, can I do with Elfinder what I'm asking for? Where can I look for it?